# Firmware-mod-kit says "No supported filesystem" along with strange and long output

Tags: binary-analysis, firmware, binary

I tried firmware-mod-kit's extract-firmware.sh script and I receive the following output which ends with "No supported filesystem found".

The firmware belongs to the TL-WR740Nv5 router.
The filesystem of the router is Squashfs 4.0.

Here's the output:
http://pastebin.com/FM9uE47t

What do I do?

Answer (score 2):

Few things to note here:

1. The reason for the overly long output is because firmware-mod-kit automatically compiles itself the first time it is run by the user. Running it again now or manually compiling before execution should yield a relatively short output.
2. firmware-mod-kit did not simply fail with "No supported filesystem found". It failed with a python error that caused a premature termination of the tool.
3. The python error was `str() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)`, which is an error widely known to come from trying to run python3 code with a python2 interpreter.